How to "refresh" or "reset" the settings of a default view?
I have a problem with the following default view:
/admin/structure/views/view/taxonomy_term

I don't believe I have ever changed it but I might be wrong and I would like to try to "refresh" or "reset" its settings to the default settings.
How to "refresh" or "reset" the settings of a default view? Should disabling and re-enabling be enough?

The simplest way in admin UI would be to delete the View and import it again. Goto /admin/config/development/configuration/single/import and select the configuration type View. Copy and paste the content of the core file web/core/modules/taxonomy/config/optional/views.view.taxonomy_term.yml
If you want to know what is going on, export the config drush cex, find the yaml file in the exported config and make a diff with the above core file. If you make any changes keep the UUID field, in this case you are working on an existing config object. After that import the config drush cim.

I made a SQL backup and tried to do that but got this error An entity with this machine name already exists but the import did not specify a UUID..

If you want to import a fresh View config object you have to delete the old one first. In Views UI where you can disable the View there is also a delete option.

I now get this error: The configuration cannot be imported because it failed validation for the following reasons: ----- Configuration core.entity_view_display.node.dp_byt.default depends on the field.field.node.dp_byt.layout_builder__layout configuration that will not exist after import..

This error has nothing to do with the imported View. It's a misconfigured content type.

I got this error when trying to import the view's details, but, I have solved the problem as described here


How to "refresh" or "reset" the settings of a default view?

Views are config, so the simple answer to that is to import a known good version of the config for that View.
If you're using config management, simply review the VCS history for the views.view.taxonomy_term.yml file, find the right version, restore it, and import as normal.
Or, if you just want to nuke it and start from scratch, copy the original core file from core/modules/taxonomy/config/optional to your config folder, then import.
If you're not using config management, you can instead copy the contents of the core file, and import manually through the UI at /admin/config/development/configuration/single/import.
Bear in mind that recommending this from afar isn't an exact science, and this assumes that your site is in the correct state to use that original file before the import. Take a backup before attempting.
Just to finish up:

Should disabling and re-enabling be enough?

That will only flip the status of the View config entity, it won't change/revert/reset any other settings (by design).

I am having trouble pasting all content of web/core/modules/taxonomy/config/optional/views.view.taxonomy_term.yml into /admin/config/development/configuration/single/import, even after deleting the "old" original taxonomy term view (more details on the comment section of the answer by 4uk4). This may have to do with the fact that my website's native language is not English. I am not sure how to proceed.
